# Error while deleting S3 objects - likely an issue with credentials but could not locate the problem

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

So I have been following other Q&A on stackoverflow and AWS SDK docs but I still couldn't delete S3 files with the following code, it simply gives the following error `Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')`

My code (s3Client.js):

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const REGION = `${process.env.S3_UPLOAD_REGION}`;

const creds = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_UPLOAD_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_UPLOAD_SECRET
};

// Create an Amazon S3 service client object.
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: REGION,
    credentials: creds 
});
export { s3Client };
```

My nextJS component:

```
import { DeleteObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { s3Client } from "../lib/s3Client.js"

const bucketParams = { Bucket: "my bucket name...", Key: "my key..." };

  const run = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await s3Client.send(new DeleteObjectCommand(bucketParams));
      console.log("Success. Object deleted.", data);
      return data; // For unit tests.
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    }
  };
```

I understand from others that this seems like a credential issue but I still couldn't wrap my head around where the problem is.

Edit:
Solution to this problem -

1. Check the .env, depending on whether you are using React or NextJS, you will need to have either "REACT_PUBLIC" or "NEXT_PUBLIC" in order for the environment objects to be exposed via `process.env`.
2. Check your permission in your S3 bucket and set "AllowedOrigins" to include your localhost. I had mine set as `"AllowedOrigins": "*"` but it wasn't enough. So I have included `http://localhost:3000` and it worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815639/typeerror-cannot-read-property-bytelength-of-undefined-aws-s3-upload

Comment: @DevangSanghani Thank you but I have checked this already and it was not that helpful.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to export your credential to browser through "REACT_PUBLIC" or "NEXT_PUBLIC", but I haven't found a better solution yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like that you're using keys credentials for this. To debug your problem the 1st thing you should do is to check the credentials outside code and SDK and make sure they're fine.

To do this, setup the credentials on CLI by setting environment variables.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Your Key here>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<SECRET HERE>
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<AWS REGION>
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

After this run this command to verify credentials are setup correctly `aws sts get-caller-identity`

If they show you the account and user details. Then delete the file using CLI. If that works then it is confirmed that issue is not with the credentials and with code. If not, it will point you in the right direction where the issue is.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I was able to verify credentials. So the problem is in the code as you have pointed out.